# HttpClient runs in local but stuck in AWS Windows Server

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I'm makin an API with net core 2.1 and run into a issue where I CAN gen a correct response in my local machine (even running the published files) BUT gen stuck when i upload and run the app in a aws ec2 windows server 2012.

I've tried using the IHttpClientFactory, adding the httpclient at services collection, making a service whith the AddHttpClient and running the release profile in my pc and with every method it runs fine in my pc but hangs in aws ec2 windows server 2012.

I'm running the app in aws ec2 with $netcore ./application.dll for now.

my pc has netcore 2.2.300 and aws 2.2.400

Here is the part of the code I use in my controller (also try with making a service):

```cs
WebCuitRequest req = new WebCuitRequest {cuit = "cuit", token = "Yt25zBH" };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
string baseUrl = "url.com/getthis";
StringContent queryString = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 HttpResponseMessage res = await _client.PostAsync(baseUrl, queryString);
//------i dont get here (no error, no response)
 HttpContent content = res.Content;
 string data = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 return data;
```

I expect an error or response but none is returned (i have a try/catch and some Console.write that never get reached).

---

Update 1 (solution):

**Moving the API I was trying to reach to a hosting without cloudfare solved the problem.** It seems that cloudfare was blocking the aws instance (but no my pc) and for some reason I didn't get a response or error. I must clarify that I have access to the target API and the posibility to move it, I don't know what can be done if you can't do changes in that env.

Tanks to Robert Perry who get me to evaluate another part on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by Azures' default security settings. I believe it locks out calls to external IP addresses by default - its worth checking this article and matching it to how your Azure is configured: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security

Comment: Thanks for your answer... the solution wasn't there but it take me to see the specific problem (cloudfare in the target api).

Answer (score 0):

**Moving the API I was trying to reach to a hosting without cloudfare solved the problem.**
It seems that cloudfare was blocking the aws instance (but no my pc) and for some reason I didn't get a response or error.
I must clarify that I have access to the target API and the posibility to move it, I don't know what can be done if you can't do changes in that env.